# Problems Playing *.m3u8 in VideoJS with videojs-contrib-hls

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, video.js, http-live-streaming

I have two HLS video playlists in the same Amazon S3 bucket (different folders). I've also created an HTTP distribution with CloudFront. I'm using the VideoJS player with the videojs-contrib-hls plugin to play the videos. One of them (let's call it `good-browser-playlist.m3u8`) plays fine; the other (let's call it `bad-browser-playlist.m3u8`) gives me a Code 4 error (`The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported`). Strangely, both were previously working fine, and I can't figure out what I did to break the one.

I have a `crossdomain.xml` file in the root of my bucket that contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross- domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

This was there when both playlists were working, and it's still there now, so I don't think it's the issue. Also, the playlists and all their files are public (both before and since the issue).

The issue started around the time when I tried to implement a bucket policy to restrict access to the bucket to my domain. The policy was basically this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy152236038454",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt152261024490",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://mydomain1.com/*",
                        "http://mydomain2.com/*",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, `bad-browser-playlist.m3u8` continues to not play even if I delete the bucket policy.

Update: How long does it take for changes in bucket policies to propagate to CloudFront? I turned the policy back on, and after a while, without my changing anything else, everything is playing in the browser. However, I can *also* play `bad-browser-playlist.m3u8` in VLC player (which I shouldn't be able to — and it correctly won't play `good-browser-playlist.m3u8`), and I cannot play either of them on iOS. It's been probably 30 minutes since I started having issues. I'm wondering how much of this is just confusion caused by my switching settings around several times before the policy had propagated. How would one know if the policy had indeed propagated? I need to reduce the number of variables in testing this.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having the same issue

Comment: I eventually got it working. 1) I removed the bucket policy because I don't think that's meant to affect CloudFront in the first place. 2) I re-transcoded my files, and 3) I realized that changes do take a while (hours+) to propagate, and stuff miraculously started working after I had waited a while, instead of wildly changing settings. And different CloudFront servers update at different intervals, so one browser/device might work and another might not during the propagation time.

Comment: Thanks so much for the update :)